# sublime text horizontal scroll keyboard

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a keyboard shortcut to scroll horizontally? I know to scroll vertically you can do `<ctrl><up>` or `<ctrl><down>`, I was hoping there would be something similar to scroll horizontally, but I've not found anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Sublime doesn't have a hotkey for horizontally.
But I did find a plugin for you to be able to do this.

[Sublime Hotkeys](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html)

[Plugin](https://github.com/TheOnlyRew/sublime-horizontal-scroll)